# What is this large growing yellow patch on my cedar hedge?

Tags: cedar

It is the start of fall here on the west coast in British Columbia, Canada. Accordingly with the start of the rainy season, I have started to rely on rainwater to keep my over 40 emerald cedars moist.

About two weeks ago I started to notice a small area on the bottom of one of my plants where the ends were starting to yellow. Today, I took a close look and took the images attached to the post. The "patch" has grown in radius and I am not sure what is causing it.

I'm not sure if it is coincidence, or some sort of "contagious" effect, but the  healthy plant beside it has started to brown in the same proximity. (See images)

The other 39ish row of plants are doing completely fine.

What is causing this issue?
What should be done next?

[image: This is a young row of trees around 5 feet tall now]
[image: The apparent "contagion"]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Other side of the country, but worth a look perhaps? https://extension.psu.edu/arborvitae-diseases

Comment: Have you used any herbicides recently?

Comment: or maybe the family dog or a small wild mammal is peeing on that area to mark its territory. Regular deposits of urine will cause selective die off of coniferous tree sections.

We also cannot discount that currents autumn temperatures have become much higher recently than even a decade ago and it is disrupting dormancy cycles across the globe. have you been overwatering or underwatering in the absence of or uncharacteristically high levels of rain in your local area?

Comment: No herbicide was used near these plants. I can't say for certain that a coyote is using this for their territory marker. That might be it, but I can't confirm unless I check my security cameras for the next while. The drip line is off and we're getting a good amount of rain for a cedar hedge.

Comment: For now, I've assumed that it could be a fungal infection and trimmed off the affected foliage. I don't see some of the symptoms of infection noted in the article. @ecnerwal